# has_many through association with additional column in the bridging table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two tables, course and category and i have a bridging table categorisations with course_id and category_id. I added an additional column to the table category_rank which is an integer for ranking the categories based on user preference. I am struggling creating entries in the database. Here are my tables:

```
  create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "is_active",  default: true
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "categorisations", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "course_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "category_rank"
  end


create_table "courses", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.string   "duration"
    t.boolean  "is_active",                     default: true
    t.integer  "state"
    t.integer  "partner_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "photo"
    t.integer  "partner"
    t.boolean  "is_published",                  default: false    
  end
```

Here are the models

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorisations
  has_many :categories, :through=> :categorisations 
  belongs_to :partner
end
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorisations 
  has_many :courses, :through=> :categorisations
  belongs_to :user
end
class Categorisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :course
end
```

When I create a course, I use a list of category objects and this works fine

```
@course.categories << @categories
```

But I now need to add a rank for each category in the bridging table

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to create a new instance for the join table - Categorization.

```
@c = Categorisation.find_or_create_by(<course and category>)
@c.rank = <assign rank>
@c.save!
```

Comment: yes but if the course/category does not exist, would it create the record?

Comment: Humm... makes sense... Don't know exactly from when I will be comfortable in Rails.. :-)

Comment: Do i need to save the course to the database before i can do this instantiation

Comment: Seems a bit messy, having to do two different saves to the database, feel like rails should handle it

Comment: @Andrew_tainton I think you could do like this too `@c = Categorisation.new(course: @course,category: @category,category_rank: category_rank)` and then `c.save!`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the extra attributes like this:

```
@course.categorisations.first.rank
```

Comment: the question is not about accessing the additional attribute. its about adding the additional attribute value

Comment: But `category_rank` is already added in the schema. I showed him how to access it through the categorisations association.. he can just assign it any arbitrary value.